# Unable to create CRUD via gii

Tags: php, yii2, crud, gii

I have generated a Model using `gii` of an `InnoDB` view, which worked.

Then trying to use the `gii` CRUD generator for the model, I am getting this error

> The table associated with app\models\Future must have a primary key(s).

I have also looked into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193050/create-a-crud-from-a-database-view-using-gii-in-yii2). But the table doesn't have any primary key and also I can't create any primary key because the DB is 3rd party DB.

Is there any way to create CRUD without having a primary key?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: CRUD without primary key  ? ... How then you perorm U. Update and D delete and R. read ? ..

Comment: What is meant by a "3rd party db"? Part of a module/extension?

Answer (score 0):

Try to define PK using:

```
public static function primaryKey()
{
    return ['name'];
}
```